# How to receive input as JSON in RESTEasy api?

Tags: json, resteasy

I have a users table having details of multiple users. I am supposed to receive an input from the front end which sends user details in **JSON** format which is to be inserted or updated in the table accordingly.

How can I receive the input in **RESTEasy** and parse it to populate the variables corresponding to the table?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, all you need is to do is define a json provider for RESTeasy (such as `resteasy-jackson-provider`), annotate the relevant resource method with `consumes("application/json")` and supply it with your domain object as an input parameter. 
The provider will do the hard work for you.

As an example, you can refer:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createUserFromJSON(User user) {
      // insert the user
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I send a json of user details from front end using RESTEasy?

Comment: Where do I store the json input to be used with the provider?

Comment: Can u please elaborate your code snippet provided above?

Comment: You don't use RESTeasy for the front end. You'll probably better to use some browser plugin (Postman, etc.) or even cURL under unix to mock those requests.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by storing the json input. You might be better reffered to some basic tutorial such as: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/json-example-with-resteasy-jackson/ let me know what you want me to add in my answer to make things clearer.

Comment: In case we don't use RESTEasy in the front end then can you tell me how can I send a JSON of user details along with the UI which a person will submit after filling the forms and submitting it?

Comment: The URL is supposed to look like this.
/secapi/1.0/users/ABC
where ABC is the user id and i want to send it's details in json format.
can you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Try https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic8purm9TLAhWiQJoKHVU1B3wQFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2Frest-easy%2F&usg=AFQjCNGAOwFfrY0-GwcIRTbLWWrN-FAIXQ&sig2=PTC14_0x8OTn-lpp7021nw